# Unity: Value still not updating - UPDATED

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

UPDATE:
The code from the answer didn't work but I had some progress, but I am still having issues. Updated.

This is my UpgradeUI script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

OnClick functions do work also with the Debug.Log. The code below is the Stats script which also updates my HealthUI.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Stats
{
    public static Stats st;
    [SerializeField]
    private BarScript bar;
    public float maxVal;
    public float currentVal;
    public int playerDamage = 20;


    public float CurrentVal
    {
        get
        {
            return currentVal;
        }

        set
        {
            this.currentVal = Mathf.Clamp(value, 0, maxVal);
            bar.Value = currentVal;
        }
    }


    public float MaxVal
    {
        get
        {
            return maxVal;
        }

        set
        {
            this.maxVal = value;
            bar.MaxValue = value;
        }
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {

        this.MaxVal = maxVal;
        this.CurrentVal = currentVal;
    }
}
```

I did progress a bit. I placed this code: 
`public void HpUp () { stats.maxVal += 20; stats.currentVal += 20; }
 public void DmgUp() { stats.playerDamage += 10; }`

into my PlayerManager and it connects with the Stats script I shared and my health does update. I removed the UpgradeMenuUI. Now the problem is that my damage does not update. Well actually it updates but the value doesn't reach where I need it to. I added a

```
 public int playerDamage;
```

in my Stats script. In my Damage script, which calculates the damage for my Player and the enemy, I changed

```
  aiManager.Enemy1Damage(playerDamage); to
      aiManager.Enemy1Damage(stats.playerDamage);
```

and I call my playerDamage from Stats into my Damage script with these:
     `public Stats stats;`
  and

```
 public void Awake()
     {
         stats = new Stats();
     }
```

So the problem is that if I change the playerDamage in my Stats script from
 `this: public int playerDamage;`
to

```
public int playerDamage = 20;
```

The value does work and my Player damage is indeed 20 when I hit the AI. However in the inspector my damage(the public int from Stats script) is 0 and if I press my upgrade damage button it goes up by 10 (that's what I set in my PlayerManager script:

```
 public void DmgUp()
 {
     stats.playerDamage += 10;
 }
```

), but that doesn't affect in any way the value 20. So it is just useless, like pumping air. I don't know how to make the public int playerDamage to update from the OnClick. If make it just playerDamage; without a number nothing updates and the damages is 0.

Comment: The issue remains.

Answer (score 1):

You have the Stats as a Singleton but are accessing a new instance of it on your button. Try changing:

```
public void HpUpgrade()
{
    stats.maxVal = (int)(stats.Instance.maxVal += hpUp);

}
public void DmgUpgrade()
{
    dmg.playerDamage = (int)(stats.Instance.maxVal += dmgUp);
}
```

I can't quite tell if you've confirmed that your OnClick event is triggering for the buttons. If they aren't, make sure that you have the EventSystem game object in your scene.

Comment: Still the same. If I do it like you I get Stats does not have a definition for Instance. If I change it like this.         stats.maxVal = (int)(Stats.instance.maxVal += hpUp);, the code is ok, but I again get the Null Reference. I had a small error in the code above about damage. The DamageScript script does come from a MonoBehavior, while Stats does not.

Comment: Actually nothing updates. Even     private float hpUp = 20;
if I change it to 40, the new value won't show in Unity Inspector.

Comment: I updated the question. I had some progress but I am still at a dead end on my damage. Health works.